# Pegar altura de uma div e aplicá-la em outra div

Tags: jquery, layout-responsivo, fullcalendar

Estou usando [o excelente plugin FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) para acrescentar um calendário em uma página do site que estou fazendo.

Ele é bem dinâmico e o plugin calcula seu tamanho assim que a página é carregada, mantendo seu tamanho proporcional ao `div` pai na qual se encontra. Isso quer dizer que seu tamanho é totalmente variável conforme o tamanho da tela.

A minha página é dividida por duas `div` ocupando cada uma 50% da tela, e em uma delas está o calendário, na outra um conteúdo aleatório. Porém preciso que essa segunda `div` possua a mesma altura da `div` do calendário, para fim de manter o layout.

Preciso de um `script` para pegar a altura do calendário e aplicá-la no conteúdo. Tentei várias alternativas aqui e nenhuma deu certo.

Observem o [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9cC6/1502/) com o código.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var events_array = [
        {
        title: 'Test1',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 20),
        tip: 'Personal tip 1'},
    {
        title: 'Test2',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 21),
        tip: 'Personal tip 2'}
    ];

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        events: events_array,
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.attr('title', event.tip);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
*,*:before,*:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
.md-6{width:50%;float:left;}
.content{width:100%;float:left;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);padding:15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css">
<div class="md-6">
    <div style="border:solid 2px red;">
        <div id='calendar'></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="md-6">
    <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed magna est. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dictum elit et lacus pellentesque aliquet. Aliquam eu orci sed urna ultricies sollicitudin. Nulla posuere, mauris eget facilisis fermentum, purus enim lobortis magna, sit amet malesuada mi metus in libero. Etiam rutrum orci quis mi scelerisque hendrerit. Proin sed lacus eros. Vestibulum eu lorem at felis cursus efficitur at ac est.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicionei duas linhas ao final do seu código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var events_array = [
        {
        title: 'Test1',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 20),
        tip: 'Personal tip 1'},
    {
        title: 'Test2',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 21),
        tip: 'Personal tip 2'}
    ];

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        events: events_array,
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.attr('title', event.tip);
        }
    });

    var tamanho = $("#calendar").height();

    $(".content").height(tamanho);    
});
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente no código funcional do site. Incrível o que duas linhas de código fazem HAHA.
Muito obrigado.